# Adding a database to an instance of SQL Server LocalDB from the command line

Tags: sql-server, localdb

I need to attach a new database to Microsoft Sql Server LocalDB from the command line.

All the examples, tutorials, etc that I've seen so far attach the database from Visual Studio or SSMS.

How can I do it from the command line?

Comment: You can use [SqlCmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/scripting/sqlcmd-use-the-utility) or the [SQL Server PowerShell Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sql-server/overview?view=sqlserver-ps).

Answer (score 1):

You can use osql.exe:

```
osql -E -S "(LocalDb)\V11.0" -Q "exec sp_attach_single_file_db 'LocalDb', 'C:\whatever\backup.mdf'"
```

You might need to exchange "V11.0" with something different depending on your version of LocalDb ... find out with "SqlLocalDb i" on the command line ...